# Timestmap of a SFTP-delivered file

Tags: sftp, timestamps, timezone

I run a SSH server (a plain `sshd`) which receives files from multiple users in different timezones/DSTs via SFTP. These files are then polled and further processed by a set of worker jobs.

In order to prevent the files not being processed (a faulty or slow worker, etc.) I decided to implement a simple check would go over all the SFTP-mapped dirs and report all files *older than X*.

The problem is the SFTP-received files on the server apparently feature **user's local timezone/DST in their timestamps** for `mtime` and - to my surprise - even `ctime`. This results in the check failing to detect files which arrived with a positive timezone offset and immediately reporting files which arrived with a negative one.

I can't seem to find a way how to normalize the timestmap of the received files to the server's local timezone or UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure your sftp-server to refuse requests to change the timestamp of a file. Look in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the current configuration line, which in my case was

```
Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
```

Run the server with the `-Q` option to list which requests can be made:

```
/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -Q requests
```

In my case this included `setstat` and `fsetstat` which presumably correspond to changing the times.  Use the blacklist option `-P` to refuse these requests in the `sshd_config` file:

```
Subsystem       sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server -P setstat,fsetstat
```

Notify `sshd` to reread the configuration by killing it with signal SIGHUP.

When I then tried `sftp` to *put* a file to the server with option `-p` which preserves times, the file was copied, but its last-modification time stayed at "now". The client saw a warning, which you will have to educate your users about:

```
sftp> put -p localfile remotefile
Uploading localfile to remotefile
Couldn't fsetstat: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I see to this problem is that you `touch` files as soon as you receive them. This will modify the accessed and modified timestamps for those files.

Source: [Touch manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/touch.1.html)

Comment: Is it 100% safe to `touch` them even though the file _might_ be still transferring (slow line, a huge file, etc.)?

Comment: @Yuri: That I have never tried. I'm sure it won't corrupt the file but I'm not sure if the timestamps will persist.

Comment: There seems to be another problem. I recall there are SFTP clients which somehow set the timestamp as the last step of the transfer. So `touch`ing the file before it is completely transferred would be useless.

Comment: @Yuri: SFTP, unfortunately, isn't my forte but, is there an option for SFTPD to run a script when a file transfer completes? You might have to look around a bit for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have a very large number of files, you can use `inotifywait` to watch for new files arriving and fix their timestamp.  (The default limit is 8192 files and directories. You can increase this, but it is probably not a good idea to go too far as it is expensive). For example, to look for files being closed after a write, or for a change in permissions or time attributes underneath directory `/dir`, recursively:

```
inotifywait -m -r -e close_write -e attrib /dir
```

This runs continuously and will output lines like

```
/dir/subdir ATTRIB filea
/dir/subdir CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE filea
```

for changes to a file `/dir/subdir/filea`.  You can write a shell script to reconstruct the filename `$f` (beware of names with spaces), and then use `stat -c %Z $f` to get its current modification time, and compare this with `date +%s`. If the absolute difference is more than a few seconds, you can use `touch` to change the file time (which will generate a new event, hence the need to ignore small differences in time).